# phpunit testing methods with $this values

Tags: unit-testing, phpunit

OK, probably a bad example. Here is an actual example. I would be wanting to unit test the total() method from a shopping cart class to see if the value is what I think it should be, which uses the getAll() (cart items), subTotal() and shipping() methods. Is total() something you could test using PHPUnit ?

```
class Cart extends ObjectModel
{

    protected $uniqueID = 10;

    public function getAll()
    {
    return $this->execute("SELECT *, cart.id AS cart_id FROM cart LEFT JOIN products ON products.id = cart.product_id WHERE cart.unique_id = ? AND cart.quantity > '0' AND cart.deleted_at IS NULL ", [$this->uniqueID] );
    }


    public function subTotal()
    {
    $subTotal = 0;
    foreach($this->getAll() as $row){
        $subTotal += ( $row->quantity * $row->cart_price );
    }
    return $subTotal;
    }


    public function total()
    {
    return $this->subTotal() + $this->shipping();
    }

    public function shipping()
    {
    if(isset($_SESSION[SALT.'shipping']) && $_SESSION[SALT.'shipping'] != ''){

        return $_SESSION[SALT.'shipping'];

    }
    /* OR RETURN DEFAULT IF SHIPPING IS NOT SET */
    return 0;
    }


}
```

The execute method is as follows, there is no constructor method for the ObjectModel class

```
public function execute($query, array $array) {

    $query = Db::conn()->prepare($query);

    $query->execute($array);

    return $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

}
```

Db::conn() is just the PDO database handle.

Comment: If you cannot tell how to set these properties, how are we supposed to know? You need to show us the whole class. However, the code you show will *always* return 25 so not sure why you need to test that at all.

Comment: Gordon, please see updated post to reflect real life situation, thanks.

Comment: Thanks, can you also provide the code for the `ObjectModel` class or at least for it's constructor and `execute` method? Your class seems tightly coupled to the database, so we need to find a way to mock/stub the database adapter.

Answer (score 0):

The class is not too well designed for unit-testing because it is *tightly coupled* to the database. In a unit-test, you want to test the subject-under-test in *isolation* of external components (here: the database). Usually, you *mock or stub* the external components with a *test double*.

Because the DB instance is hardcoded in the execute method of the `ObjectModel`, you cannot easily replace it with a test double. You could turn the test into an integration test and change the DB connection to a test database which you then populate with expected values in the tests setup method.

If you don't want to use the database at all, you can *self-shunt* the subject-under-test. This means, you use a test double of the subject-under-test itself and make execute return the expected values for your test case.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, I shall have a go using your recommendations.